# Have Ubuntu 12.04 want to instal 13.04

Tags: upgrade

I have 12.04 installed, want to instal 13.04, will it just overwrite 12.04 or do I need to uninstal 12.04.  Will my files, and other downloads still be accessable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

"sudo do-release-upgrade" will do everything you need. No need to uninstall the previous, and it will not mess with any of your user account files.

This would need to be a two-step upgrade. There is no supported method for skipping upgrades, but some quick searches around askubuntu have turned up some duplicates:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/287906/upgrade-from-12-04-to-13-04

[Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: But backup your user files first, anyway.

Comment: I think an upgrade works only for the next newest version. So upgrading 12.04 would upgrade it to 12.10 not 13.04, as he is asking. I suggest you delete or modify your answer.

Comment: @Pawan, Ah, you're correct, he'd need to upgrade to 12.10 before upgrading to 13.04. I overlooked "12.04" in the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** upgrade directly from 12.04 to 13.04 as Ubuntu only upgrades to the next newest version, i.e. running sudo do-release-upgrade would only upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 in your case, then you will have to again run the upgrade to 13.04.

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes)

> An upgrade is the process of going from an earlier version of Ubuntu
>   to a newer version of Ubuntu with an installed system. An example of
>   this would be going from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. **To avoid
>   damaging your running system, upgrading should only be done from one
>   release to the next release (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10) or
>   from one LTS release to the next (e.g. Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu
>   12.04 LTS).** If you wish to 'skip' a version, you can backup your data and do a fresh installation, or progressively upgrade to each
>   successive version. For example, to upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to
>   Ubuntu 12.10, first upgrade to 12.04, then upgrade 12.04 to 12.10.

Hence, a fresh install is recommended for you. However, if you do not want to lost data while doing a fresh install, while installing,
1. Take a backup of your files.

1. Choose to install through manual partitioning.Do not format the existing partitions(make sure all format check boxes are unchecked)
2. Install the new version on the same partition as the previous version and use the same username and password as the previous version.

> Renewing the Installation without formatting the partitions (in
>   contrast to upgrading), will also keep the personal data and
>   configurations under /home but will renew all system settings under
>   /etc as well as the default set of installed packages.

See also: [Upgrading to 13.04 Raring Ringtail](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RaringUpgrades)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perform a new Ubuntu installation and choose to keep your home folder. Of course, you'll need to reinstall your apps, but configs and stuff should stay the same. **But you always want to have a backup before doing stuff like this.** Evolution can break, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Software Updater... You can open it from the dash, of the wheel in the top right-hand side of your desktop. First you'll need to edit its settings (button in the bottom left-hand corner) :

Set "Notice me of a new Ubuntu Version" to "For any new version"

To get a notice concerning 12.10 and 13.04, which are not LTS. :-)